# Error Bot de Discord

Tags: discord.js

soy bastante nuevo en javascript y en este tipo de cosas y he intentado programar un bot básico para discord y así aprender un poco sobre esto, he seguido los pasos de un tutorial de youtube, en concreto este :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6f8x2kDdgY&t=259s
y el código que he puesto en el proyecto es este:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client;
const config = require("./config.json");

var prefix = config.prefix;

client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`${client.user.username} esta preparado!`);
client.user.setActivity("con mis amigos")
});
client.login (config.token);
```

y he instalado todo tal y como dice el video del cual he puesto el link y cuando pongo en la terminal node . me sale este error:
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema está en que el video que estás siguiendo está desactualizado. Seguramente estás intentando seguir el video pero has usado una versión muy actual de DiscordJS. Te sugiero busques un video más actualizado o sigas la documentación oficial de la versión de DiscordJS que tengas instalada. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

### Hola

Actualmente en Discord.js v13 es necesario específicar los intents que tu bot va a usar:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const config = require("./config.json");

var prefix = config.prefix;

client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`${client.user.username} esta preparado!`);
client.user.setActivity("con mis amigos")
});
client.login (config.token);
```

Ademas de, claro, activar los intents desde el [portal de desarrolladores de Discord](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Espero haberte ayudado.